# what is the difference in these two isinstances() definitions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, isinstance

1. `isinstance(list(), type(mylist))`
2. `isinstance(mylist, list)`

Is there any difference apart from the speed? I can see 2 is faster.

Comment: how did you define `array`? or do you mean the `array.array`?

Comment: Is `array` a type or an instance?

Comment: The first one is making a new list and checking if is an instance of the type of `array` (whatever that is). The second is checking if `array` is an instance of list. They are not equivalent.

Comment: ah it;s just a variable name. I'll edit the question

Comment: so you have created a variable called `my_list` which is a Python `list` and you are trying to figure out what the fastest way to check its type is. Correct?

Comment: 2. is better, don't add unnecessary function/class calls for no reason

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I measured that 2 is faster. I am actually wondering what the difference is apart from speed

Comment: @user2715898, The difference is you can *easily* use the first one incorrectly, see my example. It's not *just* about speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If used correctly, the results will be the same. But you should only use the second version.

There's no need to create an empty object, i.e. `list()`, and no reason for an extra function call via `type`.

There's also a danger you'll do something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

array = dict()

res1 = isinstance(OrderedDict(), type(array))  # True
res2 = isinstance(array, OrderedDict)          # False
```

Comment: This is a good point, the results are not always symmetric because of subclasses, of course we don't what they actually want in this case

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Yup, it's just an illustration of *what's more likely* to go wrong with the first method.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is very inefficient, as you are first creating a new list object, and then identifying the type of `my_list` and then checking if they both are same.

The second option is how the `isinstance` function is supposed to be used.